# VS Code editor places cursor after commas/quotations

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type a single comma or quotation mark in VS Code editor, the editor automatically adds a second one, which is OK, but than it places the cursor outside right after the commas, so if I need to write something between the commas (Which is normally the case...) I need to move the cursor back between the commas.

I would like to change this behavior and place the cursor automatically between commas or quotations.

Does anyone have an idea?